# Can dwm handle a keybinding sequence pressed one after another?

Tags: i3, x-dwm

Can the dwm (https://dwm.suckless.org/) window manager natively handle a keybinding sequence pressed one after another (as opposed to pressing them together simultaneously) like in spacemacs? If not, is it possible to make dwm work with something like sxhkd (https://github.com/baskerville/sxhkd)?

In i3 (https://i3wm.org/), I use

```
set $mod Mod4
bindsym $mod+w mode "workspace"
mode "workspace" {
    bindsym j workspace next_on_output
    bindsym k workspace prev_on_output
    bindsym Escape mode "default"
}
```

to get into a "workspace" mode by pressing `Mod4+w` simultaneously and then I could just use `j` or `k` to navigate the workspaces until I press `Escape`. How can I achieve the same behavior on dwm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that behaviour by applying the [Keychain](https://dwm.suckless.org/patches/keychain/) and [Cyclelayouts](https://dwm.suckless.org/patches/cyclelayouts/) patches. The configuration looks like:

```c
static Key keys[] = {
  /* ... */
  { MODKEY, XK_w, XK_j,      cyclelayout, {.i = -1 } },
  { MODKEY, XK_w, XK_k,      cyclelayout, {.i = +1 } },
  { MODKEY, XK_w, XK_Escape, setlayout,   {0} },
};
```

The Keychain patch, if you wish, can be replaced with the [Keychord](https://dwm.suckless.org/patches/keychord/) patch. The configuration then looks just a bit different:

```c
static Keychord keychords[] = {
  /* ... */
  {2, {{MODKEY, XK_w}, {0, XK_j}},      cyclelayout, {.i = -1 } },
  {2, {{MODKEY, XK_w}, {0, XK_k}},      cyclelayout, {.i = +1 } },
  {2, {{MODKEY, XK_w}, {0, XK_Escape}}, setlayout,   {0} },
};
```